# How can I reduce method duration? in Dart for loop ,If the index of the list is about 700,000, it takes 13 seconds. How can I reduce 'for Loop'?

Tags: dart

Here is the code to create a combination with the trotter package and add it to the list.
If there are about 1 million indexes, the method execution takes over 13 seconds. It seems to be taking too long and I am looking for a solution.

```
import 'package:trotter/trotter.dart';

void main() {
    comboValue();
}

List<int> _choiceNumbers = List.generate(30, (i) => i);

void comboValue() {
final start = DateTime.now();

List<List> combosList = [];
if (_choiceNumbers.length >= 6) {
    final bagOfItems = _choiceNumbers, combos = Combinations(6, bagOfItems);


    for (final combo in combos()) {
        combosList.add(combo);
    }

    int totalCombo = combos.length.toInt();
} else {}
print(combosList.length);

final end = DateTime.now();
print('method duration: ${end.difference(start)}');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Dart Observatory you can see that most of the CPU time in your program are used on BigInt operations.

[image: Output from Dart Observatory]

If you check the pub.dev page for the trotter package you can see this is a design choice:

> Since we sometimes can be working with indexes so large they cannot be represented using a 64 bit `int`, indexing and length arem implemented using `BigInt`.

And added because of the following issue: https://bitbucket.org/ram6ler/dart_trotter/issues/2/use-bigint-for-dart2-compatibility

Well, the problem with that design choice is that `BigInt` does result in a major performance impact since all operations on numbers will require additional processing even for small numbers.

The solution is to ask the developer of the package to provide some way to use the package without the use of `BigInt` or make your own fork where you change it to use `int` since I don't think the performance of `BigInt` can be much improved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to improve based on your teaching. I wish you peace in your home.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but as the author of *trotter*, I thought I'd throw in my thoughts...

In your code, your create a `Combinations` object `combos` that "stores" all the 6-combinations of the numbers from 0 to 29. You then use that to populate a list `combosList`.

However, the point of the library is to allow us to represent all the combinations without actually storing the individual combinations in memory. In other words, there is nothing we can do with `combosList` (which takes up a lot of memory and time to create) that we cannot do with `combos` (which takes up an insignificant amount of memory and time to create).

So, to me, it seems that the test you've run above should rather be something like:

```dart
import 'package:trotter/trotter.dart';

void main() {
  final start = DateTime.now(),
      bagOfItems = [for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) i],
      combos = Combinations(6, bagOfItems);

  print(combos.length);

  final end = DateTime.now();
  print("Duration: ${end.difference(start)}");
}
```

which is pretty instantaneous; I get:

```
593775
Duration: 0:00:00.012617
```

In other words, we can traverse, access, search, etc. `combos` roughly as efficiently (and search much more efficiently for large structures) as we can traverse, access, search, etc. `combosList`; the difference is that `combos` does not take up a significant amount of memory or time to put together, whereas `combosList` does. It was precisely to avoid storing all the combinatorics, which can be astronomical, that I wrote the library.

If we are dealing with, say 10-combinations of the numbers from 0 to 99, say, `combos` still takes up practically no memory or time to create whereas `combosList` would no longer even be feasible.

```dart
void main() {
  final start = DateTime.now(),
      bagOfItems = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) i],
      combos = Combinations(10, bagOfItems);

  print(combos.length);

  final randomCombo = combos.sample(1).first,
      index = combos.indexOf(randomCombo);

  print("Random Combination: $randomCombo");
  print("Index: $index");
  print("Check: ${combos[index]}");

  final end = DateTime.now();
  print("Duration: ${end.difference(start)}");
}
```

gives me:

```
17310309456440
Random Combination: [2, 13, 20, 36, 46, 53, 65, 69, 76, 94]
Index: 4247316853889
Check: [2, 13, 20, 36, 46, 53, 65, 69, 76, 94]
Duration: 0:00:00.027723
```